# Differentiability proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove that there exist some function $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=xg(x)$ and $g$ is continuous at $0$.

I think I am on the right track, here:

If I write $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ then $g$ will be discontinuous at $0$ because $f(0)=0$. Now, as an example, let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Your question is b) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338355/show-that-gi-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-and-fx-x-0gx-is-differentiable).

Comment: @DavidMitra: this is not always true!

Comment: @mookid  Oops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your definition of $g(x)$, you have $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} (f(x) - f(0))/(x-0) = f'(0)$ so you get $g(0) = f'(0)$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $1/x$ is continuous for $x \neq 0$ and the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ exists, I believe you get that $g(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Updated accordingly, thanks.

Comment: So would using l'hopital's be invalid?